# Comparing two arrays of strings in Perl based on the first two words of each element

Tags: perl

In Perl:
If I have array of strings and I want to check if part of an array element to another similar element of another array, for
example:

`$array1[0]="Word1 A 24"` and
`$array2[0]="Word1 A 50"`.

How to check if the 2 first words separated by space are matching?

I have tried to use split but I don't know if it works I'm still novice in Perl

Comment: 1) How closely should they be "matching" -- you say first two words in this example, but what is a more general criterion? 2) Does this need be done for each element of the array(s)

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way is to extract the relevant substrings and compare them.

In the example of "the first two words with space between them" a regular expression is easiest

```
my ($ss1) = $ary1[0] =~ /(\w+\s+\w+)/;
my ($ss2) = $ary2[0] =~ /(\w+\s+\w+)/;
if ($ss1 eq $ss2) { ... }
```

The pattern `\s+` matches any amount of whitespace between the first two words, what may differ between the strings.<sup>†</sup>  The pattern `\w+` matches a string of consecutive "word characters," and parenthesis around the whole pattern are there to "capture" the match.

If you need to allow yet more (or exclude some) use a "character class," for example `[\w-]+` matches a word character or a `-`, once or more times.

The parens around the variable (`$ss1` etc) are needed to provide the "list context" for the regex match so that it returns the captures.
To check for each array element iterate over the index

```
use List::Util qw(min);

for my $i ( 0 .. min $#ary1, $#ary2 ) {
    my ($ss1) = $ary1[$i] =~ /(\w+\s+\w+)/;
    my ($ss2) = $ary2[$i] =~ /(\w+\s+\w+)/;
    if ($ss1 and $ss2 and $ss1 eq $ss2) { 
        say "The first two words and space between them are the same at $i"; 
    }
}
```

( Or use  
`my ($ss1, $ss2) = map { /(\w+\s+\w+)/ } $ary1[$i], $ary2[$i];` )

This compares positions in arrays up to the last one in the shorter array, where the syntax `$#arrayname` is for the last index in the array `@arrayname`.  If your arrays must be the same length then you don't need that but can iterate to the last index in either, and check lengths of arrays beforehand instead.

This can be equipped with further checks, and there are other ways to organize it.

Please provide more detail.

---

<sup>†</sup> And if you really need the words to match, regardless of the amount of space between them, then `split` is good

```
my @words1 = split ' ', $ary1[0];
my @words2 = split ' ', $ary2[0];

if ($words1[0] eq $word2[0] and $words1[1] eq $words2[1]) { ... }
```

The patter `' '` in [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) is special: it breaks the string by any amount of whitespace, and drops leading and trailing spaces.

There are other ways to organize this.  Then you'd do this in a loop over your arrays, like shown further in the answer for example.

Comment: Your index loop is going too high by one; you should count up to the min of `$#ary` instead of `scalar @ary`.

Comment: @MarkReed Absolutely, was in rush and got pulled away, just fixed it.  Thank you for comment

Comment: @Dibo The question did get closed, but I did answer it and now have added a bit